# Provide to somebody to do/doing or Provide for somebody to do/doing?

Tags: grammar, infinitives, gerunds

I'm writing a letter to my teacher to thank her for letting me put on a party, but I'm confused by these:

> I would like to thank *somebody* for your support, guidance and
> encouragement, and for the opportunities provided to *me* to organize
> this event.
>
> I would like to thank *somebody* for your support, guidance and
> encouragement, and for the opportunities provided to *me* to organizing
> this event.
>
> I would like to thank *somebody* for your support, guidance and
> encouragement, and for the opportunities provided for *me* to organize
> this event.
>
> I would like to thank *somebody* for your support, guidance and
> encouragement, and for the opportunities provided for *me* to organizing
> this event.

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use any of these. I would instead use:

> I would like to thank you for your support, guidance, and encouragement, and for giving me the opportunity to organize this event.